# scala - print top to down vendor segments

Tags: scala

In scala, how do I generate a list of hierarchy strings - eg for a vendor company that provides services like below

```
/Vendor/Platform/DataServices
```

to

```
/Vendor/
/Vendor/Platform/
/Vendor/Platform/DataServices
```

Right now, I use a function like below,

```
scala> def hier_str(a:String,b:Int):String =
     | {
     |
     | for(i<- a.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1=='/').map(x => x._2 ).zipWithIndex )
     | if( i._2 == b )
     | return a.substring(0,i._1)
     |
     | return a
     |
     | }
hier_str: (a: String, b: Int)String

scala> for(i<- 1 to 3) yield hier_str("/Vendor/Platform/DataServices",i)
res40: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(/Vendor, /Vendor/Platform, /Vendor/Platform/DataServices)

scala>
```

Is there a better way to generate it easily using inbuilt functions alone?.

Comment: Why can you just split and then fold?

Comment: @RamanMishra.. could you pls show that, if it is helping to avoid function, I'm fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `scanLeft` method, which appears in scala 2.8

The `scan` just do a `fold` and store the intermediate result:

```
string.split('/').drop(1).scanLeft(""){(acc, next) => acc + "/" + next}.drop(1)
```

output when printing every element:

```
/Vendor
/Vendor/Platform
/Vendor/Platform/DataServices
```

Check out the official documentation
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html

Here is a scalafiddle to demonstrate it

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/A7GEFaM/10

Comment: there is any empty element at the end.. You need to strip that using drop(1)

Comment: @stack0114106 You are right, I edited my answer for you, does it filfull your needs or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a
  .split("/")
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .inits
  .map(_.mkString("/","/",""))
  .toList
  .reverse
```

This includes the root element `/` so add `.drop(1)` if you don't want this.

This may or may not be better than code using custom functions...

Comment: please revise ````value reverse is not a member of Iterator[String]````

Comment: it doesn't print from the root

Comment: @stack0114106 Many apologies, that was broken in so many ways. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

This small function would do it:

```scala
def split(path: String): String = {
  val filteredList = path.split("/").zipWithIndex.filter(_._1.nonEmpty)
  filteredList.map {
    case (text, index) =>
      (0 until index).map(i => filteredList(i)._1).mkString("/")
  }.mkString("\n")
}

split("/Vendor/Platform/DataServices")
/* should output
Vendor/
Vendor/Platform/
Vendor/Platform/DataServices
*/
```

Comment: yes.. this also works.. just add one more ````/```` to the first mkString

Answer (score 0):

**I think this will solve your problem:**

```
val str1="/Vendor/Platform/DataServices"
val p=str1.split('/').drop(1).scanLeft(""){case (x, y) => x + "/" + y}.drop(1).mkString("/"+"\n")
println(p)
```

Comment: this is same as the accepted answer.. pls cross check before you post the answer